# Using Logs in stored Procedure

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

I need help in creating logs in a stored procedure. 
Scenario is like:
I am creating a procedure. I need to log some intermediate information from the procedure in a log file, such that each time the procedure is executed the logs are generated.

Normally i was using SPOOL for this purpose, but as SPOOL is SQL PLUS and cannot be used in PL/SQL, i was look for a better way through which logs written to specific file each time the procedure is triggered informing the updates which are made in the procedure.

Can someone please help me in identifying any such code snap which i can insert in the stored procedure in order to meet my requirement.

NOTE: I am using Oracle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply create a package with simple logging functionality, which opens, writes and closes a log file that is stored on the database server. Look into the [UTL_FILE package](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_file.htm);